# strange file loading times on windows

Tags: c++, windows, file, caching

On windows 7, I have two files A and B on the desktop. 
These files have custom formats.
I load them in my application one by one (load A first in application; exit application, open application again and then load B).
A loads in 20 secs and B loads in 10 secs.

I restart the machine to remove windows file caching effects (I am measuring load file performance).
Now I load file B and then file A. Now B loads in 20 secs and A in 10 secs.

These two files have nothing to do with each other and my application has no special logic which could explain this behavior...then how is this explainable? 
One thought that came to my mind is dll files might have been cached ? Can this be a reasonable explanation for such a large difference ?

Another question : is there a better way to measure load performance(including I/O) preferably which doesn't involve machine restarts?

(Of course, if I load A twice without restarting machine the load time is much less..this I think is due to windows file caching)

Comment: Have you tried loading some non-related file C, and then timing the load times of A and B? Have you profiled the code to see if it is the read calls from the filesystem that is causing the variance, or something else?

Comment: If Windows file caching has much in common with CPU memory caching, perhaps the fact that the files are in the same directory, probably created about the same time and probably adjacent on the drive means that loading one 'caches' all or part of the other?

Answer (score 0):

can you try creating files with the flag:FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, and load those to see the performance results? files with this flag should always be read from physical disk rather than windows file system cache.

resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx